# Threads in SurfaceView

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I am making a game in Android and I actually have a Thread for that game:

```
public class ThreadEscribir extends Thread{
    EscribirJuego pantalla;
    boolean pintar=false;
    SurfaceHolder sh;
    Canvas canvas;
    private static int FPS=10;


    public ThreadEscribir(EscribirJuego v, SurfaceHolder surf){
        pantalla=v;
        sh=surf;
        canvas=new Canvas();
    }


    public void run(){
        //marcamos cada cuanto queremos que se actualice la pantalla
        long ticksPS=1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;

    while(pintar){


        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            canvas=sh.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(pantalla.getHolder()){
                pantalla.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        }

        finally{
            if (canvas!=null)
                sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        //hacemos que el tiempo de refresh de todos los smartphone sea el mismo
        sleepTime=ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        try{
            if(sleepTime>0)
                sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                sleep(10);
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }


    }

    public void estado(boolean e){
        pintar=e;
    }



}
```

This works perfect, but now I need a thread for the bitmaps of my **surfaceview** that the user can move with the finger, and I dont know how to start it.I used the same code that for ThreadEscribir but changed `pantalla.onDraw(canvas)` for a for loop which calls the `ondraw` of each bitmap that I have to move, but I does not work well because now the bitmaps blink and leave a trail. How could I do a a correct thread?

Comment: You need only one thread, that thread does all the drawing.

Comment: But the game is very slow